# How to run multiple watir scripts from one general script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting, cmd, watir

I have 3 different watir scripts testing different functionality of a website. I want to be able to run one single script which brings these different scripts together and runs them one after another. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to require all files explicitly in one file and then run that file. For example, you have Watir code in `file1.rb`, `file2.rb` and `file3.rb`. Create `file.rb` that contains:

```
require "file1"
require "file2"
require "file3"
```

and then in command line execute `file.rb` with:

```
ruby file.rb
```

Comment: Ah thanks I thought it would be more complicated than that, I'll give this  a go.